# How to play tv channel in exoPlayer from link (Live Stream as on TV)

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to develop a TV player with a bitrates option (Managing Video Quality like in YouTube).
My player plays all videos except the live stream (TV Channel from the link).

Solutions I tried:

Answer1: [Error playing HLS stream with Google Exoplayer on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544280/error-playing-hls-stream-with-google-exoplayer-on-android)

Answer2:
[Exoplayer v2, live video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991270/exoplayer-v2-live-video-stream)

I tried some other answers on StackOverflow and read some blog but didn't help.

**Below is my code if anyone can help me to solve the issue. Following activity also contains code for managing stream speed**

```
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.DefaultMediaSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isShowingTrackSelectionDialog;
    private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
//Below line is for video speed option
    String[] speed = {"0.25x","0.5x","Normal","1.5x","2x"};
 
    //Below ARE WORKING URLS becuase video is present on server and is not live
    //String url1 = "https://5b44cf20b0388.streamlock.net:8443/vod/smil:bbb.smil/playlist.m3u8";
   // String url1 = "https://5b44cf20b0388.streamlock.net:8443/vod/smil:ed.smil/playlist.m3u8";
    //String url1 = "https://5b44cf20b0388.streamlock.net:8443/vod/smil:sintel-hd.smil/playlist.m3u8";
   
//Below are urls don't work because these are for tv channels
     // String url1 = "https://stream.commec.tv/iframe/b/169562/c/5707742";
       String url1 = "http://app.pakistanVision.tv:1935/live/PTVnews/player.m3u8";
      //String url1 = "http://cdn.ebound.tv/tv/expressentertainment/chunks.m3u8";
      //String url1 = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hls-playground/hls.m3u8";
     // String url1 = "http://192.168.0.102:8001/1:0:19:4E89:14:70:1680000:0:0:0:";
       // String url1 = "http://cspan1-lh.akamaihd.net/i/cspan1_1@304727/index_1000_av-p.m3u8";

    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this);


  simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView);
        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
       

 /*When used the below code it doesn't work for anything           
            simpleExoPlayer =
                    new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
                            .setMediaSourceFactory(
                                    new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this).setLiveTargetOffsetMs(5000))
                           .build();
    
            MediaItem mediaItem =
                    new MediaItem.Builder()
                            .setUri(url1)
                            .setLiveMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.02f)
                            .build();
            simpleExoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem); up-to here*/




 simpleExoPlayer.addMediaItem(mediaItem);
            simpleExoPlayer.prepare();
            simpleExoPlayer.play();


        ImageView farwordBtn = playerView.findViewById(R.id.fwd);
        ImageView rewBtn = playerView.findViewById(R.id.rew);
        ImageView setting = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_track_selection_view);
        ImageView speedBtn = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_playback_speed);
        TextView speedTxt = playerView.findViewById(R.id.speed);



        speedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Set Speed");
                builder.setItems(speed, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // the user clicked on colors[which]

                        if (which==0){

                            speedTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            speedTxt.setText("0.25X");
                            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(0.5f);
                            simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);


                        }  if (which==1){

                            speedTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            speedTxt.setText("0.5X");
                            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(0.5f);
                            simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);


                        }
                        if (which==2){

                            speedTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(1f);
                            simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);


                        }
                        if (which==3){
                            speedTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            speedTxt.setText("1.5X");
                            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(1.5f);
                            simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);

                        }
                        if (which==4){


                            speedTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            speedTxt.setText("2X");

                            PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(2f);
                            simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);



                        }



                    }
                });
                builder.show();





            }
        });


        farwordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 10000);

            }
        });
        rewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                long num = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 10000;
                if (num < 0) {

                    simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);


                } else {

                    simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 10000);

                }


            }
        });

        ImageView fullscreenButton = playerView.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
        fullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                int orientation = MainActivity.this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    // code for portrait mode

                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


                } else {
                    // code for landscape mode

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Land", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                }


            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.exo_play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                simpleExoPlayer.play();

            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.exo_pause).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                simpleExoPlayer.pause();

            }
        });


        simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {

                }

            }
        });


        playerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

            }
        });


        setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isShowingTrackSelectionDialog
                        && TrackSelectionDialog.willHaveContent(trackSelector)) {
                    isShowingTrackSelectionDialog = true;
                    TrackSelectionDialog trackSelectionDialog =
                            TrackSelectionDialog.createForTrackSelector(
                                    trackSelector,
                                    /* onDismissListener= */ dismissedDialog -> isShowingTrackSelectionDialog = false);
                    trackSelectionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), /* tag= */ null);


                }


            }
        });

    }

}
```

**XML For Above JAVA CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fram"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoPlayerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/ustom_controls"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
            app:show_buffering="when_playing">

        </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**My Build.Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stremobuilders321.stremoplayer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Beside all the above I am using Custom Control xml Layout (For media player buttons), and a class to control bitrates, if needed I'll provide both of these too.

The Error my Application gives: **E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error**

**Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect**

It works fine for stored videos on servers, but doesn't work for live stream tv channels gives above error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download this sample at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr1H33Pe7u-MW93UUpmMUhGTTQ/view and modify Uri

```
video_url = "http://cspan1-lh.akamaihd.net/i/cspan1_1@304727/index_1000_av-p.m3u8";
```

Note: some m3u8 files wont play because of incorrect format
Check for supported formats here https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html

Comment: This code is too old, and work fine for video store on server but for TV channel links it shows black screen nothing else. I tried your provided link still the same no effect...

Answer (score 0):

try setting mime type

```
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri(uri)
                .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
                .build();
```